# How to get the public and private keys of an account from Metamask | ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, private-key, public-key, metamask

I have been searching recently on how to get the public and private keys of ana account from Metamask that is used with ethereum blockchain. However, I was not able to find any useful sources.

Do you know any way to get it?

Comment: You can get the public key, but not the private key from MetaMask. MetaMask is a Web3Provider, which maintains the privates keys within itself, and signs transactions when requested, without exposing the private keys. If you are able to obtain the private key from MetaMask, that would be a serious security issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get private keys out from MetaMask programmatically. This is the whole point of having a wallet is that the user confirms the transactions and is in control of their own assets.